# Issue with multiple ajax calls simultaneously using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery for ajax calls

All the calls are called immmediately on page load and we are getting the responses at almost the same time.

the issue is, the 3 calls are fired and I am getting the data, but the callback function is fired for the first call only.

the other two callbacks are not called, the callback is defined as a separate function,

If I just write an alert instead of calling the callback method, all the 3 alert message are coming

So the issue is when we write the callback method, do any one have any idea of the strange behaviour?

We tried to reorder the calls, the behaviour is similar, which ever is called first, its callback will be called, for the rest, it will not be called

```
var url = "/test1";
    ajaxCall(url, testMethod1, false);   



var url = "test2";
        ajaxCall(url, testMethod2, false); 

var url = "test3";
            ajaxCall(url, testMethod3, false); 

testMethod1:function(data){
    console.log("first"+data);
},
testMethod2:function(data){
    console.log("second"+data);
},
testMethod3:function(data){
    console.log("thrid"+data);
}
```

ajaxCall is defined as jquery ajax, the issue is only the testMethod1 is called, the rest 2 are not called

Regards
Hari

Comment: You have to show us the entire ajaxCall function and how  you're calling it

Comment: what does you console say ?

Comment: Check ajax requests in firebug console, how many requests you will see.

Comment: and btw why are you assigning a different values to url variable twice ?

Comment: @steo i meant he could just call ajaxCall("test1", testMethod1, false); ... and so on !

Comment: don't you have `error` callback function in your jquery ajax, try assigning to them.

Comment: The ajax call is below, $.ajax({
   url : url,
   success : callback,
   type : method,
   data : requestData,   
   dataType : "json"
   
   
  });   I am getting all the 3 responses, after the success, the callback is called for the first one only

Comment: the only differences i see in this code (it not help we because is incomplete) is that "test2" and "test3" haven't the slash before like "/test1" and maybe if your application route not solve the urls you has an error 500 and callback will not fire

Comment: Hi, there is no issue in the requests and its response, only thing is, the callback for the second and third are not called, only the first call callback is called

Comment: `success` callback is correctly fired by ajax call?
thy to put a `console.log()` inside the `ajaxCall` success callback like: 
`$.ajax({ url : url, success : function(data){console.log("success:",this);callback(data)}, type : method, data : requestData, dataType : "json" });`
and see the logs - if you have a only one console.log success there are something gone wrong in the request (maybe in JSON parse code:201)

Comment: Thank you Frogmouth, we just implemented what you said, we were getting only the success message for the first one only, so we added the error also, in which we found that we have some error in the response for the second and third calls which we corrected, thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing that immediately caught my eye is that the URL for test1 has a forward slash preceding test1. This means that you are using a valid link in only test1. The alerts will trigger because you are probably not trying to access the data returned (which would still work even though the ajax request fails), where as you are trying to access the data in the coded call back functions you have provided, which will obviously throw a NullPointerException or whatever the equivalent as the ajax call fails due to an incorrect URL. Therefore data never gets set and the code doesn't work.